# Showing sequences are / aren't Cauchy under different norms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For the sequence $g_n \in C[-1,1]$ defined by $g_n = x^\frac{1}{2n-1}$ how would you show that $g_n$ is Cauchy under $\|\cdot\|_1$ but not under $\|\cdot\|_\infty$?

$\|f\|_1 = \int_a^b |f|$ and $\|f\|_\infty = \sup|f(x)|$ .

Comment: Are you considering here $||\cdot ||_{1}$ and $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ as the $L^{1}$ and $L^{\infty}$ norms?

Comment: Ah, I've edited in what the norms are defined as.

Comment: I'd just compute $\|g_n-g_m\|_1$ and $\|g_n-g_m\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $g_n$ converges pointwise to the function
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }0<x\le1,\\0&\text{if }x=0,\\-1&\text{if }-1\le x<0.\end{cases}
$$
Check that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1|g(x)-g_n(x)|\,dx=0$ and deduce that $\{g_n\}$ is convergent in the $L^1$ norm, and hence Cauchy.

On the other hand, if $\{g_n\}$ were Cauchy in the $L^\infty$ norm, since $C[-1,1]$ is complete for that norm, its limit would be continuous. But $g$ is not continuous.